# How to append AAR library versionName to my application versionName?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have a locally generated AAR library (generated as a module from another Android Studio project) which is imported to my Android application project. I want to set the versionName of the application project to be a concatenation of the AAR library versionName and the application versionName.

I have something like this in my mind (in the application `build.gradle`)

```
android {
...
    defaultConfig {
    ...
        versionName "1.2.3-"   // app semantic version
        versionNameSuffix <getMyAarVersionName>   // my library version name
```

The result would be something like `versionName = 1.2.3-<aarVersionName>`

Is it feasible to do so in gradle?